# Grouping rows and merge output HTML cells using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to group a span of rows into so that I can set the background color of each set alternatively. I would also like to merge the first column into one cell. Here is what I have done so far.

**XML**

```xml
<Action>
    <Step>
        <Obj>UC_A</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>abc</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>bcd</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>cde</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>UC_B</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>def</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>efg</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>UC_C</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>abc</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>bcd</Obj>
    </Step>
    <Step>
        <Obj>cde</Obj>
    </Step>
</Action>
```

**XSL**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Action">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    table { table-layout:auto; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:Arial; }
                    td { vertical-align:top; border:1px solid Silver; padding:0pt; font-size:9pt; padding-right:3px; padding-left:3px; }
                    tr.ODD { background-color:#FFFFDB; }
                    tr.EVEN { background-color:#E9FFFF; }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>  
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Step">
        <xsl:variable name="UCBgColor">
            <xsl:if test="starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')">
                <xsl:variable name="IsOddEven">
                    <xsl:number count="Step[starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')]"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$IsOddEven mod 2 = 0">EVEN</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>ODD</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable>

        <tr class="{$UCBgColor}">
            <td>
                <xsl:if test="starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')">
                    <xsl:number count="Step[starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')]"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Obj" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Current Output***

[image]

***Expected Output***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a `rowspan` attribute use an approach like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="5.0" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="group" match="Step[Obj[not(starts-with(., 'UC_'))]]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Step[Obj[starts-with(., 'UC_')]][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Action">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type="text/css">
                    table { table-layout:auto; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:Arial; }
                    td { vertical-align:top; border:1px solid Silver; padding:0pt; font-size:9pt; padding-right:3px; padding-left:3px; }
                    tr.ODD { background-color:#FFFFDB; }
                    tr.EVEN { background-color:#E9FFFF; }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Step[starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')]"/>  
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Step[starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')]">
        <xsl:variable name="UCBgColor">
            <xsl:if test="starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')">
                <xsl:variable name="IsOddEven">
                    <xsl:number count="Step[starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')]"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$IsOddEven mod 2 = 0">EVEN</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>ODD</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('group', generate-id())"/>
        <tr class="{$UCBgColor}">
            <td rowspan="{1 + count($group)}">
                <xsl:number count="Step[starts-with(Obj, 'UC_')]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Obj"/>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <xsl:apply-templates select="$group">
            <xsl:with-param name="UCBgColor" select="$UCBgColor"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Step[not(starts-with(Obj, 'UC_'))]">
        <xsl:param name="UCBgColor"/>
        <tr class="{$UCBgColor}">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Obj"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiK9/2.

Comment: I did tried something similar but the problem is that it shifts the other columns to the right because the <td> is getting assigned blank values in step template.

Comment: Updated your code which fixes the column moving to right problem.

Comment: @PankajJaju, you are right, the code needed a fix to make sure only for the first `tr` row of  group a `td rowspan="..."` is created. If the problem is now solved you can accept the answer.

Comment: One of the problem is resolved. Thanks. However, the color coding a block of rows is still pending.

Comment: @PankajJaju, I have edited the code to address that problem.

Comment: Works great. The only issue is performance. On using the code on my actual XML (which is much larger), the grouping using Key is bit slow.